# Mac App Store apps start download then freezes when download starts and never continues

Tags: applications, mac-appstore

I start downloading an app and it starts to download but the download bar never goes up at all. It just stays at the beginning of the download as shown in this picture:

[image: Example screenshot showing progress bar at beginning of process]

When I go to the Mac App Store it just keeps refreshing my screen and having a seizure or something.

[image]

I can't download or play this game I really wanted for a very long time.

Comment: Oh and It stays at that same exact position forever